# Setup Elastic Load Balancers in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to setup ELB in my AWS hosted website. I figured that for ELB, two instances must be present for load balancing and than load balancers are applied to them.

I have one EC2 instance running already and want to create another instance. I am a newbie to the concept of ELB so I am confused how the second instance must be launched?

Shall I launch the instance with same EBS volume the previous instance is working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rajat ,

ELB diverts the traffic equally across the availability Zones ,assume in Singapore zone , there are 2 zones available , SO ELB equally diverts ur traffic across both the zones . SO you need to maintain **equal number** of **identical servers** on both the servers ,so that ur traffic can be maintained equally and to avoid extra load on one machine .Both the servers on each zone must be of same instance type for proper load handling . Hope it answers for your doubt .

Comment: I understand that each zone must be of same instance type but my query is that they should work on same EBS volume or i should create a new volume using snapshot of previous working volume?

Comment: Your both the instances should be identical ,i mean both the instances should be deployed identically ,if u deployed ur code on EBS volume , So better take a snapshot of it and create a volume out of that and attach to the other instance. Make sure u have identical instances across the zones .

Comment: I worked on your saying but i figured a problem. In my website, i continuously make changes to my database stored in EBS volume and snapshot stores the data till the time it was created. Then, how other instance will be able to work on updates done in the EBS volume after snapshot was created?

Comment: it seems u have deployed App and DB in a same instance ,If its so , u r doing in a wrong way , Its good practice to have app and DB in a separate instance . So create a Separate DB instance (or u can use RDS for it) , point ur app instances which is attached to ELB to that DB instance (or RDS) .so u wont face the issue which u is encountered now.

Comment: Thanks i was trying to apply Elastic load balancing with a wrong approach.